# Not notified of unwanted edits to question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, tags, editing

I was surprised to see one of my questions being changed that much that the intent of the question was removed from it.

As C++ is evolving rapidly, I was experimenting with one of its features: constexpr. However, it did only take a few hours to remove the mentions of constexpr from both the title and tags. Even worse, it was replaced by the tags constants, which is as relevant as a tag called classes or object oriented programming.

In order to give a taste of what I was trying, I used a well-known concept (sudoku) as base for the code.
I explicitly did not mention sudoku as tag, since this was not relevant to the question other than reducing a large into to explain the code.
Yet, this appeared in both the title and the tags.

From all of this, I do have some questions:

- Why did I not get a notification that my question received an edit?
- Although no constexpr tag exist, this is the single most relevant one, yet a moderator changed this and undid my rollback (twice). How to proceed with getting the tags in order
- Why can't I report incorrect edits?
- Do you agree that sudoku should not be in as a tag, nor in the title?

Related question: [Constexpr unit tests and asserts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/195282/103739)

Answer (score 11):

Let's try adressing the questions first and then some more general stuff:

> Why did I not get a notification that my question received and edit?

[This MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/222299) suggests that edits need to meet certain criteria to trigger a notification. You **should** have received a notification for the change in title.

> Although no constexpr tag exist, this is the single most relevant one, yet a moderator changed this and undid my rollback (twice). How to proceed with getting the tags in order

The [constexpr](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constexpr) tag has been synonymized with the [constants](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constants) tag. If you disagree with that, I highly suggest splitting that out into a separate meta question.

For some reason or other you kept rolling back to a revision with a tag named [c++2a](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a). Which C++ standard is 2A?

Additionally Revisions 4 - 7 suggest that you're not really familiar with how rollbacks work. Seeing without context a rollback to revisions 2, 3, 2, 1 (in that order), I'd have to assume that you actually wanted to change something **based** on revision 3, and roll back to that first.

The tags of the question are at the time of writing:

```
c++ sudoku constants c++20
```

That seems just fine to me.

> Why can't I report incorrect edits?

Because you can unilaterally roll them back. What are you trying to achieve by reporting them?

> Do you agree that sudoku should not be in as a tag, nor in the title?

Huh? The problem domain of your question is a [sudoku](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku). While your question is not formulated around that and you're asking about a different aspect of the code, that doesn't mean it's irrelevant.

Tags are not there for you to like them, they're there to help categorize a question without needing to open and read it. If a tag helps categorize a question better than no tag, that tag should be added. If you don't have tags left to spare, you should trade off the usefulness of categorizations against one another.

In summary: **No**, I do not agree it shouldn't be there. (also it is not in the title...)

---

> As C++ is evolving rapidly, I was experimenting with one of its features: constexpr.

the [Cppreference site on constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) suggests that constexpr has been available since C++11. The semantics changed a little through the standards.

> Even worse, it was replaced by the tags constants, which is as relevant as a tag called classes or object oriented programming.

["It means *constant expression*"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp). At least according to Microsoft's C++ Docs. Oh and from earlier linked cppreference:
"specified that the value of a variable or function can appear in constant expressions".

I'd say [constants](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constants) is an appropriate enough synonym for now. As noted above: Concerns about the tag synonymization should be handled in a dedicated meta post to elicit a community-consensus.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are conflating the concept of a constant with the `const` keyword. While `const` and `constexpr` have very important and distinct usages they are both at their core constants.